# Mustache filetype in Helm template partials

Tags: vim, kubernetes-helm

In some Helm Chart examples, the template partial file _helpers.tpl contains the following first line:

```
{{/* vim: set filetype=mustache: */}}
```

Can you explain it ? How is mustache used in Helm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These things are called "modelines", they are used to override default options for the current file. See `:help modeline` in Vim.

They are usually included as comments so as not to break your code. For example, in a `*.c` file, you could find something like:

```
 // vi:set ts=8 sts=4 sw=4 noet:
```

because that is how comments are written.

In your *helm* files, the following:

```
{{/* vim: set filetype=mustache: */}}
```

is a modeline:

```
vim: set filetype=mustache:
```

included in a comment:

```
{{/* ... */}}
```

which tells Vim to assign the `mustache` filetype to the buffer, because the templating syntax is very close to Mustache. The point, here, is simply to give Vim users at least *some* syntax highlighting for Helm files.

Answer (score 1):

Mustache *isn't* used in Helm.  It uses the Go [text/template](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) language instead.

From a text editor's point of view, though, both formats contain templating constructs inside `{{ double curly braces }}`.  If you tell vim that the file is a Mustache file, even though that's technically wrong, it's "close enough" that you'll get reasonable syntax highlighting.

From Helm's point of view, `{{/* ... */}}` is just a comment and gets ignored.

Comment: (I have had horrible trouble with Emacs `web-mode` getting the indentation wrong, since it strongly expects the non-template content to be HTML rather than YAML.  Emacs uses a similar marker `{{/* -*- mode: web -*- */}}`.)